# How to do ignore quit() **and hide()** main window in closeEvent() in PyQt?

Tags: qt, pyqt

I want to do ignore quit **and hide** main window in closeEvent(), but closeEvent couldn't ignore program exit() while press Command-Q.

Test environment: MacOS, latest PyQt and Qt.

My code snippet a:

```python
# ...

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

# Why it doesn't works ?
# For more detail http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#quitOnLastWindowClosed-prop
app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)

# ...
```

snippet b:

```python
# ...

def closeEvent(self, event):
    if self._settings["close_confirm"]:
        btn_val, new_settings = ExitTipsDialog.get_input(settings=self._settings, parent=self)

        if btn_val == QtGui.QDialog.Accepted:
            if new_settings["close_main_pannel_action"] == MINIMIZE_WHILE_CLOSE_MAIN_PANNEL:

                # Oops, QApplication::lastWindowClosed() signal is emitted
                self.hide()

                event.ignore()
                return
        else:
            event.ignore()
            return
    else:
        if self._settings["close_main_pannel_action"] == MINIMIZE_WHILE_CLOSE_MAIN_PANNEL:
            event.ignore()
            self.hide()
            return

# ...
```

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#close said:

> The QApplication::lastWindowClosed()
>   signal is emitted when the last
>   visible primary window (i.e. window
>   with no parent) with the
>   Qt::WA_QuitOnClose attribute set is
>   closed. By default this attribute is
>   set for all widgets except transient
>   windows such as splash screens, tool
>   windows, and popup menus.

How to do ignore quit() **and hide()** main window in closeEvent() ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to handle the hide event in `closeEvent`. There's `hideEvent` for that.

If this is not what you mean, perhaps you should clarify your question.